# Text should be on the line of the textarea

Tags: html, css

This is my [url](http://caremerge.us/quater/form1.html) where you'll see the textareas with the Dashed line some thing like the following:

---

---

---

All I am trying to do is that whenever i wrtie then the text being witten on the lines of the text area and on enter text should be entered from the second line and so on. Currently the text is being written on the first line but it got messed up for other lines. Following is my css for the text area. Kindly let me know how can i accomplish this functionality that text should be written on each line .

Thanks!

```
.textdash
{
border:1px; border-style:solid; background-image:url(images/text.jpg);  background-repeat:repeat; font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif; font-size:18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to `.textdash { }`

`line-height: 23px;`

I would even recommend to adjust your background image to be a few pixels shorter or taller and then adjust `line-height` until you get it right.

Comment: Thanks moin bhai i totally forgot about line-height in css

Thanks for the help now i'll resolve the issue..

Comment: 23px appears good with the 3-line textarea on the provided page, but anybody can resize the textarea (and that's a good thing). Then appears the same shift problem that OP had: the background image has a height of 24px, not 23. So it should be **`line-height: 24px`** and also `background-position: left 1px` to have one more px between baseline of text and the background line

Comment: @FelipeAlsacreations Thanks for updating with more improved code. Now my issue is being 100% REsolved